# Why do I get �-Chars even though everything is in UTF-8?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I’m struggling with an UTF-8 problem. I did everything what is pointed out here: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

### Summary

I'm aware of all the "standard" PHP, MySQL and HTML Settings for UTF-8, but I still have some unexpected behavior. I think it has to do something with a broken file (aka charset setting), or hidden character or something, but I don't know how to check & fix that.

**Why do I think that?**

1.) The W3C Validator is unable to check my page: [informel1.de](https://informel1.de)

```
Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 1 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8
```

2.) My test page (same DB, same DB connection-file, same PHP config file) works fine:

[Testpage](http://test.informel1.de/)

How can I check or even clean up my file? I did a copy/paste into a blank file already (without a result).

Any idea? I'd be happy, even on how to find out which error that could be, and not the solution.

**The problem:**

UTF-8 works fine for everything which does NOT come out of the DB (= directly in PHP or HTML). Every UTF-8 char from the DB is either a "?" (e.g. Emojis) or a "�" (e.g. German Umlaut). Inside of the DB (phpmyAdmin or I use Sequel Pro), everything looks correct.

[screenshot of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV0qY.png)

**What I've done so far:**

Checked the editor: VS Code uses UTF-8

**index.php**

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

**HTML:**

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

**Server:**
user.ini, because it’s a shared hosting and I don’t have access to php.ini

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

**php-configs:**

```
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Because I only see the problem with my DB (and not with php-only-content), I checked everything there:

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin (or general_ci)
```

**DB Connection:**

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4");
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
```

**What else I’ve done:**

- I checked everything twice (source code, phpinfo, dev tools, etc.) and everything looks as described
- Checked the DB with SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
- Switched back to PHP 7.X
- I also tried different settings (e.g. .htaccess AddDefaultCharset or changed the encoding to utf8 instead utf8mb4) but nothing made a difference.
- I also made a fresh & simple testpage, when I get the data out here, it looks fine.
  [testpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSNwb.png)
- I copied everything from my index.php to a blank document and saved it again.
- I don’t see any errors in my error.log
- I don’t have access to mysql settings in etc/mysql/my.cnf. Otherwise, I could try something like:

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

Due to the fact that I set the charset & collation in my DB, it shouldn’t be a difference.

- I asked the web hosting support. They cannot help, because it looks like an application-, and not like a server-setting-problem.
- I checked the W3C validator and got a strange behaviour. I cannot check the page with UTF-8, only with UTF-16. The error message:  Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 1 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
  The error was: Modification of a read-only value attempted (I cannot find anything useful on that message)

Comment: you don't need any mysql settings. Speaking of **database**, all that matters is the charset of your **tables** (or columns, for that matter). As long, as: 1. The table charset is utf8mb4; 2. The data in the table is *actually* encoded in utf-8; 3. mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4"); is called, you should get your data sound and safe

Comment: I would bet on #2. It seems the data import was incorrect somehow. #1 is also the possibility though. The diamond "�" sign means that the browser expects an utf-8 encoded umlaut but gets single-byte encoded one

Comment: @YourCommonSense Okey, thanks, but what does it mean? If you're right and the data import was incorrect, how can I fix (or even check) that? As mentioned above, I do mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4") already, and I still get the error. In addition, my check-page with the same DB behind works without error. If the data is the problem, it would be the same here, wouldn't it?

Comment: What is check page and how do you get data for it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I made a test page to check if the data is correct here: http://test.informel1.de/ . It's the same DB and I use the same php config and DB connection-file.

Comment: Well it looks like some code on the main page is breaking the data then

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: (I changed the "dup" link to better address "black diamonds".)

Comment: Thanks for every idea so far. I've tried a few more things but I'm still struggeling with everything what comes out of my DB. The post is closed due to duplicate (which I don't think it is), but I can't describe more than I already did...

Comment: There's room in the Comments to provide the output for the `SHOWs` and `SELECTs` mentioned in the dup.